# Handle “Enter” in an EditText and insert character in it

Tags: android, android-edittext, event-handling

I have an `EditText`. I want that whenever user press enter key, automatically insert a number(incremental numbers). Should I use `TextWatcher` interface or `OnEditorActionListener` ? If I use `TextWatcher`, how to recognize `enter` key.
I do this, but nothing happened.

```
 View.OnKeyListener onEnter = new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                edtInput.addTextChangedListener(new HandlEventEditText(edtInput));

            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

and `HandlEventEditText` class

```
public class HandlEventEditText implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        editText.setText("4");
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `TextWatcher` and do it inside `afterTextChanged()`.

Comment: Have you tried: `edittext.setText("4")` in Keylistener thing?

Comment: press enter when focus in edittext or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use like this:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
        //If the keyevent is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            //...
            // ...
            // ...    

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can enter the logic there, and your Enter key will do as you say.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I press the enter, program does not enter the body of `if` statement at all !!!

Comment: I tested this before, but no change was made.

Comment: @sarina Check now, the other answer.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot

Comment: @sarina Consider accepting and Upvoting it please, So that even I'll get some benefit :)